# Is it possible to use ruby refinements to change the behavior of a controller action in tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stubbing, refinements

Is it possible to use the refinements feature to stub a controller action?

I am defining the refinement in "my_controller_refinement.rb"

```
require "my_controller"

module MyControllerRefinement
  refine MyController do
    def create_item(my_object = {})
      return "test_id"
    end
  end
end
```

And using it in the test as follows -

```
require_relative "my_controller_refinement"

class MyControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  using MyControllerRefinement

  test "get item" do
    post :create { my_object: { name: "Test", id: "test_id" } }
    # Post redirects to the show page
    assert_redirected_to action: "show", id: "test_id"
  end
end
```

The test dir is as -

```
test/
  -->  my_controller_refinement.rb
  -->  my_controller_test.rb
```

But the refinement doesnt kick in and the actual controller action seems to get called.

Am I missing something or can refinements not be used for such "stubbing" ?

Comment: You're probably better off using a [mocking library](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/mocking) instead. Additionally [ActionController::TestCase is depreciated in Rails 5](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/04/19/changes-to-test-controllers-in-rails-5.html) so you might want to rethink and get with the program of integration over controller tests.

Answer (score 2):

This won't work because of the way [Refinements](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html) work currently. The docs (cited below) have the full scoop, but in essence the scoping on a refinement is very narrow.

> You may only activate refinements at top-level, not inside any class, module or method scope. You may activate refinements in a string passed to Kernel#eval that is evaluated at top-level. Refinements are active until the end of the file or the end of the eval string, respectively.
>
> Refinements are lexical in scope. When control is transferred outside the scope the refinement is deactivated. This means that if you require or load a file or call a method that is defined outside the current scope the refinement will be deactivated.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but from the docs, this is my understanding
`c.rb  -->  my_controller.rb,  m.rb   --> my_controller_refinement.rb,  m_user.rb --> my_controller_test.rb`

Are you suggesting I move the `using MyControllerRefinement` outside the class? (I have tried this as well and it doesnt seem to work)

Comment: Or could it be that due to `ActionController::TestCase` the lexical scope is not as expected and hence the refinement can never kick in?

Comment: “Are you suggesting I move the using MyControllerRefinement outside the class?” No, I opened with “this won't work”. I don't know why you thought that may have been suggested. Per the documentation, this isn't going to work. 1) You can't activate a refinement inside of a class, 2) the refinement will be deactivated when you call another method. Since you're not directly calling `@controller.new` from your test (the library is), the refinement won't be active.

Comment: Since the blurb you pasted contained both the top-level activation and lexical scope, I was just trying to understand what was your suggestion. Thank you for clarifying that up! As I commented earlier, I had a hunch that the lexical scope was just not right. Will try to explore that.

Answer (score 0):

As another answer mentions, refinements are lexically scoped, which means they're only active in the space between the `class` and `end`. I can show this with an example:

```
class OrigClass
  def test_method
    # checks if some methods are defined and calls them if they are
    puts (!! defined? patch_method_1) && patch_method_1
    puts (!! defined? patch_method_2) && patch_method_2
  end
  # the refinement will attempt to overwrite this method
  def patch_method_1; 0; end
end

puts OrigClass.new.test_method # => 0 false

module Refinement
  refine OrigClass do
    # this method is already defined on OrigClass
    def patch_method_1; 1; end
    # this one is not
    def patch_method_2; 2; end
  end
end

# re-open the class to add the refinement
class OrigClass
  using Refinement
  puts new.test_method # => 0 false
  puts new.patch_method_1 # => 1
  puts new.patch_method_2 # => 2
end

puts OrigClass.new.test_method # => 0 false
```

The final two calls to `test_method` don't use the refinement methods because of the lexical scoping. This is not using your exact use-case (controller actions) but it is the same concept, and shows that refinements prove difficult to use in this way.

Comment: Nice example @max-pleaner, but I believe they are behaving just as they are supposed to!

Lets say at the point you re-open the class, you rename the class to say `OrigClassTest` and do `puts OrigClass.new.patch_method_1`, you will see the refinement kicking in.

In the context of my example, the reopen of the class to add the refinement corresponds to the test using the refinement.

Comment: Maybe what I am missing is the way tests are generated with the superclass `ActionController::TestCase` and hence I need to rethink the way I am trying to refine the controller action.

Comment: The thing is, your test case doesn't explicitly call the method you're altering via refinement. It's presumably called behind the scenes somewhere, so the refinement won't activate.